# scm connection vs developerConnection

Tags: maven, maven-scm

Can anyone tell me the difference between scm connection and developerConnection in maven?

I am trying to build using `mvn release:prepare` and it requires either one of them.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project was-topology-legacy-dsl: Missing required
>   setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified. ->
>   [Help 1]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As mentioned in [POM Reference: SCM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM)  The `connection` requires `read access` for Maven to be able to find the source code (for example, an update), `developerConnection` requires a connection that will give `write access`. It is an information for our project where the other, including with another `maven plugin` to re-use this information further. In this case the `Maven Release Plugin`.

The [Maven Release Plugin: Prepare a Release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) also provides us the behind the scenes what it does for us during the `release:prepare`. There are some significant steps which requires the access to the `scm` as the following: -

1. Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
2. Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
3. Commit the modified POMs

This means we should provide the `scm` information when using the `maven release plugin`. Especially the `developerConnection`. If we don't provide, the plugin is not able to execute.

Another useful information is [Maven Release Plugin: Perform a Release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) and [Maven Release Plugin: Rollback a Release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html).

Comment: So connection = read only, developerConnection = read/write. Thanks.

Comment: If a developerConnection (write access) is provided, why also provide connection ?

Comment: Thus the error message saying
"scm connection OR developerConnection must be specified"

Comment: @chrisinmtown the read + write can be done via different means. eg. the read could be a ssh and the write could be https. So you'd need both.