# Github fails to checkout from SCM - SSH

Tags: eclipse, maven, github, ssh, version-control

I am trying to use maven-release-plugin:2.5.3.

My repository on github is working with ssh. Push and pull works fine.

When entering `ssh -T git@github.com` in Terminal I get the correct answer from github:

```
"Hi UserName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."
```

When entering `./mvnw release:prepare` in Eclipse Terminal I get Build Success.

But when entering `./mvnw release:prepare` in Eclipse Terminal I get the following Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project ProjectName: Unable to checkout from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Cloning into '/Users/UserName/git/RepoName/ProjectName/target/checkout'...
[ERROR] remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
[ERROR] remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
[ERROR] fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UserName/RepoName.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My POM looks like this:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:UserName/RepoName.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
            <goals>install</goals>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My ssh config file looks like this:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github/github_rsa
```

In Eclipse `Preferences General->Network Connections->SSH2`, I have the following private keys:

```
/Users/UserName/.ssh/github/github_rsa,id_dsa,id_rsa
```

And the SSH2 home:

```
/Users/UserName/.ssh
```

It looks as if GitHub was still trying to connect via https: but I don´t see how or where.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The problem is: `The requested URL returned error: 403`...

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure maven release is using the [right private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53229242/6309).

Second, as long as you see:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UserName/RepoName.git/':
```

No amount of SSH setting will work: if the remote repository is access through HTTPS, SSH key won't be used. At all.

You might want to set [`connection` as well as `developerconnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664961/6309) to an SSH URL, using the syntax:

```
scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/UserName/RepoName.git
        ^^^
```